# Go issue when passing Windows path as CLI args

Tags: windows, go, path

I am building a small CLI that takes as arguments two paths. It works fine on Linux and macOS but when using absolute paths on Windows, it breaks. This issue is illustred by the snippet bellow :

```golang
// absPath is something like "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Some.Folder\"
globPath := filepath.Join(absPath, "*.pdf")

// got: "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Some.Folder"\\*.pdf" 
// want: "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Some.Folder\\*.pdf"
fmt.Println(globPath)
```

The CLI takes two args which are both path which are passed as bellow:

```
> go-cli "C:\Users\John\dest\" "C:\Users\John\Desktop\Some.Folder\"
```

In this specific case, both are Windows absolute path. I should also specify that this CLI is getting args via `spf13/cobra` module.

I found the following workaround:

- Using relative path, in which case the issue is solved but I don't want to rely exclusively on relative path.
- Escaping the path which I do not want to do (nor the user doing)
- Removing the final trailing slash in the path

To clarify this issue as asked by some, why are absolute windows paths passed via args not retrieved correctly and cannot be properly manipulated inside my Go program ? (cf. example above with an invalid path produced by the `filepath.Join` function)

Comment: Please clarify your problem. It is difficult to understand what you ask

Comment: I just added some extra infos

Comment: `filepath.Join()` does not produce the 'invalid path' you show. Have a look. [https://go.dev/play/p/fj1TQUHc5z8]

Comment: I cannot access your snippet and the issue likely comes from passing the args via a shell

Comment: Unfortunately parsing command line arguments [gets complex](https://daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINNOSTANDARD). Your example arguments include `\"` which could be parsed as `\ ` followed by `"`, or as `"` (an escaped quote). I'm not sure that there is a "right" way to deal with this (your program will probably behave as expected if you run it from powershell). See [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17149) for (a lot) more info. One option is to not include the trailing `\ ` (`cmd.exe` command completion excludes this - e.g. `"c:\Program Files"`).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and for the linked resources ! I guess I'll have to warn users of this caveat.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the asterisk filename outside of filepath.Join like this:

```
    absPath := "C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\Some.Folder\\"
    globPath := filepath.Join(absPath, "/") + "*.pdf"
    fmt.Println(globPath)
```